# .Net Core 5 MVC not working delete action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, crud, .net-5

Delete action not firing, eventhough every other action is working just fine.
I am getting 405 or 404 output. Of course, Id is not null, a lot of different enterences.
What could be a problem?

Here is my Controller:-

```
    public IActionResult Delete(int? id){
            if (id == null || id == 0) {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var obj = _db.Expense.Find(id);
            if (obj == null){
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(obj);
        }
        // POST Delete
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult DeletePost(int? id){
            var obj = _db.Expense.Find(id);
            if (obj == null){
                return NotFound();
            }
            _db.Expense.Remove(obj);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

And here is my View
Nothing spetial, just calling POST action, like usual.
:-

```
@model InAndOut.Models.Expense

<form method="post" asp-action="DeletePost">
    <input asp-for="Id" hidden />
    <div class="border p-3">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <h2 class="text-black-50 pl-3">Delete Expense</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
               //here is form
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-8 offset-2 row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger w-75" value="Delete" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-success w-75">Back</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is my defaul MVC Routing:-

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

Comment: The database most likely does not have such an id and it returns null. Or your id is invalid or null too. Сheck it with a breakpoint

Comment: [404 Not Found](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404) / [405 Method Not Allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405)

Comment: Where is your delete button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been doing the same tutorial and for me the actions work. Please take a look at my code. If you have further questions please contact me. Here's my repo: https://github.com/andreeapurta/AppointmentApplication

controller:

```
            [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public IActionResult DeletePost(int? id)
            {
                var expense = dbContext.Expenses.Find(id);
                if (expense == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                //get items from DB
                dbContext.Expenses.Remove(expense);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
    
            //Get - delete
            public IActionResult Delete(int? id)
            {
                if (id == null || id == 0)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                //get items from DB
                var expense = dbContext.Expenses.Find(id);
                if (expense == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
    
                return View(expense);  // return the view with out object so we can display the info we are getting
            }
```

html:

```
<form method="post" asp-action="DeletePost">
    <input asp-for="Id" hidden/>
    <div class="border p-3">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <h2 class="text-black-50 pl-3">Delete Expense</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="ExpenseName"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="Amount"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <input asp-for="ExpenseName" disabled class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <input asp-for="Amount" disabled class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-8 offset-2 row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger w-75" value="Delete" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-success w-75">Back</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
@*client validation*@
@section Scripts{
    @{
        <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
    }
}
```

model:

```
  public class Expense
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string ExpenseName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(1.00, 4000, ErrorMessage = "Amount must be greater than 0 and less than 4000")]
        public float Amount { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Expense Type")]
        public int ExpenseCategoryId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ExpenseCategoryId")]
        public virtual ExpenseCategory ExpenseCategory { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form asp-controller="Write here name your controller" asp-action="DeletePost" method="post" >
    <div class="border p-3">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <h2 class="text-black-50 pl-3">Delete Expense</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-8 offset-2 row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger w-75" value="Delete" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn success w-75">Back</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Try to remove `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` I'm not sure that help but just try

Comment: @Alex  `<input type="number" asp-for="Id" hidden />` try to add "type="number"

Comment: @Alex By the way, if I'm not mistaken, then you obviously do not need to specify input, since the id should not come in the form, but in the query string. And you pass it in the form. Just try to remove input

Comment: Didnt work..
Input here is for specifying Id, whatever input we are using. The exact Id that is passed from controller, i belive

Comment: Tried your new answer and put in with answers before, still nothing...(

Comment: @Alex I have updated my answer. Try it if it doesn't work I don't know what to do

Comment: Nothing(
But anyway, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This was tested in VS2019 and is working properly (assuming your id is not null)

```
@model InAndOut.Models.Expense

<form asp-action="DeletePost" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" method="post" >
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
.....
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger w-75" value="Delete" />
                        
</form>
```

or you can use classic mvc submit

```
@model InAndOut.Models.Expense

<form asp-action="DeletePost" method="post" >
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<input asp-for="@Model.Id" hidden />

.....
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger w-75" value="Delete" />
                        
</form>
```

and action for this view

```
[HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult DeletePost(Expense expense)
```